# Everytime I try to use Subdivision Surface the App Crashes

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm using a ASUS ROG G14, Windows 11 laptop. I have downloaded the most recent graphics card, have turned off GPU Subdivision Surface, and nothing has worked. I've gotten Subdivision Surface to work on other objects. I don't know what to do.

Comment: You haven't given enough details for us to even guess what is causing the problem. Add a screenshot of the object you're trying to use the modifier on to your question and share the blend file with just that object in it via https://blend-exchange.com/ and we might be able to help.

Comment: i wish i could download hardware...you have to show me that trick!!! :D

Comment: @Chris As long as it's a free download! :^)